# Which sequence_length do we use for tf.nn.ctc_loss

Tags: tensorflow

I generated a tensor for training a RNN, the input is of size `[batch_size, max_time_step, num_features]`, but as multiple training samples do not have the same `time_step`, I padded them with zeros at the end to match the training sample which has the the `max_time_step` for that particular batch. The `train_seq_len` however has the actual `time_step` values of each input sample in a one dimensional vector `[batch_size]`. With respect to the labels, they are present in a sparse tensor of shape `[batch_size, max_label_size]`, where the label vectors which are smaller than `max_label_size` are padded with zeros.

My question is for `tf.nn.ctc_loss(inputs, labels, sequence_length)`, the `sequence_length` required here is `train_seq_len` I have defined above? Or is it `label_size_len`, a one dimensional vector of size `[batch_size]`, containing the `label_size` of each label vector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sequence_length is the latter:  the batch size length vector.

Comment: Hi Eugene, just to clarify the `sequence_length` input required is associated to `labels` and not the `inputs` in `tf.nn.ctc_loss(inputs, labels, sequence_length)`

Comment: no, sequence_length is associated with the inputs.  labels' lengths are usually much shorter than the actual input.  since the inputs tensor is padded (because the pre-rnn input is padded), sequence_length tells you where the valid (pre-rnn) inputs are.